# Find out which page an item is on

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using LINQ with entity framework in my application. I have repository method to get a page of data like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Sample> GetPageData(int orderId, int page, int itemsPerPage)
{
    var samples = _context.Set<Sample>()
                          .Where(s => s.OrderId == orderId)
                          .OrderBy(s => s.Id)
                          .Skip(itemsPerPage * page)
                          .Take(itemsPerPage);

    return samples;
}
```

I would like to have another repository method so that I can retrieve the page on which a sample is. The method signature would be something like:

```
public int GetPage(int orderId, int sampleId, int itemsPerPage)
{
    // ???
}
```

I am struggling to find a way to do it in LINQ. The only idea I have for now is to fetch the pages one after one until I find the needed sample. I know it is not efficient but the requirement is that there are no more than 500 samples and the page size is 25.

How I could do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int GetPage(int orderId, int sampleId, int itemsPerPage)
{
    //protect against divide by zero
   if(itemsPerPage < 1)
      return 1;//or 0 if you want page index

  int index = _context.Set<Sample>()
                       .Where(s => s.OrderId == orderId && s.Id < sampleId)
                       //.OrderBy(s => s.Id) edited after accepted OrderBy not necessary
                       .Count();

   //if index is zero return 1
   //if index == 9 and itemsPerPage == 10 return 1 
   //if index == 10 and itemsPerPage == 10 return 2
   //if you want the page index rather than the page number don't add 1
   return 1 + (index / itemsPerPage);
}
```

@Rob Lyndon's effort made me think some more, and I came up with this as a way of checking that the page actually contains the sample - in one query to the database

```
public int GetPage(int orderId, int sampleId, int itemsPerPage)
{
    //protect against divide by zero
   if(itemsPerPage < 1)
      return 1;//or 0 if you want page index, or -1 if you want to flag this as invalid

   var result = context.Set<Sample>()
                .Where(s => s.OrderId == orderId 
                            && s.Id <= sampleId)//this time include sampleId
                //.OrderBy(s => s.ID)  edited after accepted OrderBy not necessary
                .GroupBy(x => true)
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    MaxID = group.Max(s => s.Id),
                    Count = group.Count()
                })
                .Single();

  //Check the sample is actually in the result
  if(result.MaxID != sampleId)
      return 1;//or 0 if you want page index, or -1 if you want to flag this as invalid

  int index = result.Count - 1;

   //if you want the page index rather than the page number don't add 1
   return 1 + (index / itemsPerPage);
}
```

Comment: This implementation is the more complete and is really doing only one query with the database.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of the `OrderBy(s => s.ID)` clause. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2266486 I realised this on a re-read. Your comment beat me by seconds in my edit!

Answer (score 2):

```
public int GetPage(int sampleId, int itemsPerPage)
{
    return _context.Set<Sample>()
                   .Count(s => s.Id <= sampleId) / itemsPerPage;
}
```

Comment: The `OrderBy` is on the `Id` column, and the `Where` on the `OrderId` (`SampleId`) column. So unless you can guarantee the result is identical when ordering the result by those two columns (what you generally can't), this won't work.

Comment: If the sampleId provided is not in the set, then the method will return a unpredictable result.

Comment: @Grant Winney The OP's query contains a `Skip(itemsPerPage * page)` assuming we use the same convention, `int page` should be 0 for the first page.

Comment: @Merwan If sampleId is not there, the query would return on which page it would appear if it is added.

Comment: @ken2k I think you are suggesting that `OrderBy` is necessary here but you just need to get the count of items less than `Id`, you don't need to order them. But the `Where(s => s.OrderId == orderId)` is missing

Comment: @GrantWinney I'm saying we shouldn't add 1 to the result to be consistent with the OP's convention (`page` is a zero-based index)

Comment: The original question didn't include an `orderId` parameter in the `GetPage()` signature. This is why my answer don't contain the `Where(s => s.OrderId == orderId)` clause.This can be added, but I think the `OrderBy` is irrevelant.

Comment: The original question didn't include an `orderId` parameter in the `GetPage()` signature. This is why my answer don't contain the `Where(s => s.OrderId == orderId)` clause.This can be added, but I think the `OrderBy` is irrevelant.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int GetPage(int orderId, int sampleId, int itemsPerPage)
{
    var samples = _context.Set<Sample>()
        .Where(s => s.OrderId == orderId)
        .OrderBy(s => s.Id)
        .Where(s => s.Id <= sampleId)
        .ToList();

    var lastSample = samples.LastOrDefault();
    if (lastSample == null || lastSample.Id != sampleId) return -1;

    return (samples.Count - 1) / itemsPerPage;
}
```

Comment: ToList() pulls the whole data set into memory rather than just retrieving the count.

Comment: It doesn't pull in the whole dataset -- just the filtered entries.  Without the ToList(), the set would be enumerated twice: once in the LastOrDefault() invocation, and once in the Count() invocation.

Returning -1 indicates that the sample you're searching for is not in the dataset.  The value I'm returning is zero-based, to match the scheme from the original question, so -1 makes perfect sense in that context.

Comment: We have IQueryables here so without the ToList() you would run 2 different queries on the database and in most cases I suspect that would be more efficient. If you really need to check it's on the page, I'd even prefer checking that after the actual page fetch to fetching all records up to that page

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean.  A count and a single fetch might be two enumerations, but the chances are they're cheaper than bringing the whole filtered list into memory.  BTW, the original query started at page 0 (passing 0 in as the page number gives the first batch of records).  All very C#.

Comment: Indeed, it brings the whole filtered entries in memory. It is not necessarily a problem as we are dealing with less than 500 samples in our use case. Another issue is that we cannot remove the `ToList()` as LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `LastOrDefault()`.

Comment: @Merwan to remove the `ToList()` you could reverse the sort and use `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I can get the reverse order with `OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)` (`Reverse()` does not work with Linq to Entities).

Comment: Linq to Entities is a joy to work with, is it not? :)

Comment: @RobLyndon Sorry but your comment cannot be translated into a store expression. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The assumption here is there is (at least) an entry for the given sampleId and orderId.

```
public int GetPage(int sampleId, int itemsPerPage, int orderId)
{
   return _context.Set<Sample>().Count(s => s.OrderId == orderId && s.Id < sampleId) / itemsPerPage + 1;                
}
```